# How to skip user chosen dates in MS Excel autofill?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am given a start date that I enter into a cell. Then I do a fill down 100 days.  It then sequentially will fill in all the days.  There is a setting to exclude weekends which I applied.  So now it is the next 100 weekdays.  The problem I have is that I need to be able to skip other holidays.  For example what if I want to skip 7/4/2014 which was a Friday? I can use VBA if necessary.

Comment: Untested, but a Google search reveals this: [Autofill Dates Excluding Certain Weekdays](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/510472-autofill-dates-excluding-certain-weekdays-3.html).

Comment: Checkout the `WORKDAY(start_date, days, [holidays])` formula as well. The `[holidays]` variable allows you to refer to a range of cells that include the days (holidays) that you want skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the start date in A1, e.g. for this financial year:-

4/1/2014

and the list of dates you want to skip in column B starting in B1, e.g. (as in the question)

7/4/2014

and put the formula using WORKDAY as suggested in A2

=WORKDAY(A1,1,B$1:B$1)

and pull the formula down as required.

As a Brit, I've just realised that 7/4/2014 means Fourth of July if the dates are in MM/DD/YYYY format.